# Laws for light absorbtion

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, absorption

When light of one particular wavelength is directed to a surface, it may get completely or partly reflected, or completely absorbed.
Is the amount of reflected light always proportional to the intensity of the incoming light, i.e.,
$$
E_\text{out} = \alpha E_{\text{in}}
$$
$0 \le \alpha \le 1$, or is the relationship more complex?

Answer (score 0):

The amount of reflected light will always be less than the incoming light. And yes since there is no negative light, it will always be greater than or equal to 0. Determining alpha can be complex though, for any given scenario.

Comment: The question is asking for the *mathematical relationship* between incident and reflected light. I don't see how simply stating that `reflected light is non-negative and less than incident light` answers the question. This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/355765)

Comment: I'm saying the math already posted is right. They didn't ask what alpha is.